# Confused about the dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1 = (2,-1,1)$ $v_2 = (a,b,c)$ and $v_3 = (d,e,f)$ such that $v_1 \perp v_2$ and $v_1 \perp v_3$.
Using the dot product, we have
$$ 2a - b + c = 0$$
$$ 2d - e + f = 0$$

$v_2 = (1,2,0)$ and $v_3 = (1,1,-1)$.

$v_2$ and $v_3$ should both be perpendicular to $v_1$ (dot product equals 0) but they are clearly not parallel. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In three dimensions, being perpendicular does not imply being parallel. Infinitely many vectors may form a plane that is defined by a single unit normal vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations all appear correct, you may write that $(1,2,0)$ and $(1, 1, -1)$ lie on the plane given by

$$2x - y + z = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

To go a bit simpler, choose $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$. These all have dot product zero with one another and none of them is parallel to the other one. It's not clear why you think that $v_2$ and $v_3$ should be parallel, but this is not so.

In fact in three dimensions we can always make a new vector which is perpendicular to any two vectors using the cross product,
$$v\times w=(
v_2w_3-w_3v_2,
v_3w_1-w_1v_3,
v_1w_2-w_2v_1)
$$
You can check that $v\cdot v\times w$ is zero and similarly for $w$, thus this is perpendicular to both $v$ and $w$.